# Change the Imput Format for dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently trying to create a spreadsheet which organizes data found in a generated .csv report. The dates in the .csv file are formatted "201611 - (November 2016)". Is there a way to make excel recognize this as a date?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make excel recognize this as a date?

Not straight way. Excel stores dates as numbers, but counting from 1/1/1900, so 201611 won't be November 2016, you need to use some formula:

In a new column enter the formula:
`=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),RIGHT(A2,2),1)`

Change the number format (right click - format cells - number) to:

- category: custom
- type: `mmmm yyyy`

[image]